# I have a set of latlong bounds and I want to know a hotels in those bounds. Are there any freely available APIs / databases to do so

Tags: android

I have a set of lat long bounds and I want to know all available hotels in those bounds. Are there any freely available APIs / databases to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best shot is probably [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/?csw=1). It gives you a list of landmarks around a point and you can filter the results.